# Cover full screen with div - RWD overflow's

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design

I try to make info block which will slide up after button is clicked and will cover entire available screen. I encounter problem with smaller device, text overflow sliding div. Can i ask you for some solution ?

You can find working example here : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yYxOwe

HTML

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button id="more-info" href="#about" type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
            <figure id ="logo">
                    <img class="navbar-brand" src="http://cleartheairchicago.com/files/2014/06/logo-placeholder.jpg" alt="logo" title="logo" width="150px" />
                    <figcaption>Under construction page</figcaption>
                </figure>

            </div>

</nav>



    <!--  About Page-->
        <div id="about" class="top-tab offscreen container-fluid col-md-12">
            <section class="col-md-4">
                <h1>About Us</h1>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc non turpis ut enim consequat elementum et a lectus. Cras dui massa, condimentum non arcu non, pretium gravida sem. Maecenas at mattis ipsum. Aliquam erat volutpat. Donec nec nibh sed odio euismod pellentesque non vitae purus. Aenean pretium varius erat sit amet fringilla. Phasellus ac justo nibh. Donec suscipit est vel euismod facilisis. Maecenas accumsan nunc eget nunc tempor ornare.</p>


            </section>

            <section class="col-md-4">
             <h1>What we offer</h1>
                <p>orem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc non turpis ut enim consequat elementum et a lectus. Cras dui massa, condimentum non arcu non, pretium gravida sem. Maecenas at mattis ipsum. Aliquam erat volutpat. Donec nec nibh sed odio euismod pellentesque non vitae purus. Aenean pretium varius erat sit amet fringilla. Phasellus ac justo nibh. Donec suscipit est vel euismod facilisis. Maecenas accumsan nunc eget nunc tempor ornare.</p>



            </section>

            <section class="col-md-4">
                <h1>Contact Us</h1>
                  <p>orem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc non turpis ut enim consequat elementum et a lectus. Cras dui massa, condimentum non arcu non, pretium gravida sem. Maecenas at mattis ipsum. Aliquam erat volutpat. Donec nec nibh sed odio euismod pellentesque non vitae purus. Aenean pretium varius erat sit amet fringilla. Phasellus ac justo nibh. Donec suscipit est vel euismod facilisis. Maecenas accumsan nunc eget nunc tempor ornare.</p>




            </section>

        </div>
```

CSS

```
 body {background-color: blue;}
.top-tab {
position: absolute; 
transition: 0.5s all;
top: 0;
background-color:white;
opacity:0.85;
height: 100%;
padding-top: 4%;
}
.offscreen {top: -9999px;}
.navbar-header {
  float: none;
}
.navbar-toggle {
  display: block;
}
.navbar-collapse {
  border-top: 1px solid transparent;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
}
.navbar-collapse.collapse {
  display: none!important;
}
.navbar-nav {
  float: none!important;
  margin: 7.5px -15px;
}
.navbar-nav>li {
  float: none;
}
.navbar-nav>li>a {
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

JS

```
   $(function() {
  $("#more-info").click(function(event) {
    var href=$(this).attr('href');
    $(href).toggleClass('offscreen');
    event.preventDefault()
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `overflow:auto;` to your `.top-tab` class in your CSS.

**Edit in Following part of code:**

```
.top-tab {
position: absolute; 
transition: 0.5s all;
top: 0;
background-color:white;
opacity:0.85;
height: 100%;
padding-top: 4%;
overflow:auto; /* ADDED */
}
```